# How do I autowire an object from code I depend on?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class as such.

```
public class Foo {

  @Autowired
  private Bar bar;

}
```

The class Bar lives in a jar that comes from a dependency pulled in from Maven. How can I add that class to the Spring context so that it will be properly autowired? I can't add the @Component to the source code. Is there a way to do it without XML? I'm currently trying to stick with annotation driven injection as much as possible.

I'm using Spring 3.1.4-RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your description that you know exactly which class is being instantiated. If that's the case, then in one of your `@Configuration` classes, you can simply create the appropriate bean, and Spring will configure it before deployment into the context:

```
@Bean public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So the @Configuration class allows me to create beans? I've used a Provider in Guice that does sort of the same thing.

Comment: @Jazzepi Look into JavaConfig (the working title and the still-usual name for it). You have to make sure Spring grabs your initial `@Configuration` (either by listing it in an XML file somewhere or using it as a context entry point), and then you can component-scan other configurations and just create beans of anything using regular Java syntax. The bean will by default be named the same as the method name.